# How can I make a good favicon?

Tags: favicon

I have a 16x16 PNG that I want to use for my favicon. It works fine in modern browsers, but I need a favicon.ico file for older ones. The problem is that either the ICO format doesn't support semi-transaprency, which my favicon uses, or the converters I've found online don't support it.

Which is it? If the format supports it, how can I convert a PNG to an ICO with semi-transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](http://mintywhite.com/more/software-more/create-a-transparent-favicon-for-your-website/) a website I found using photoshop and a website to do it.

[Here's](http://www.revolutionwebdesign.com/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=8B1F9EB1-D1B9-61C4-09F428DC29AF6230) another website I found that deals with the Windows ICO plugin for Photoshop - located [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Plugins/ICO-file-format.shtml).

Warning: I have NOT tested that file download for exclusion of viruses - download at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

If Christopher's links don't help, simply try changing the file extension from .PNG to .ICO - that's worked for me in the past.

Comment: With transparent .ico's too?

Comment: Honestly - I can't remember, and I don't have anything handy to test...

Answer (score 0):

For handling image formats, I've found irfanview to be the best (and free).
See: http://www.irfanview.com/